# Blocking Access to Certain Sites

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have a weird setup on a server we host: the site hosts both live and test versions of its sites, set up in two different folders, D:\Live Sites, and D:\Test Sites. What would be the best way to block all except four specific IPs from accessing any of the sites inside D:\Test Sites?

Is there a way to do this while delivering a specific error page to incorrect IPs?

The server is Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the "IP and Domain restrictions" IIS role service (under Web Server > Security). Once installed, you can configure IP/hostname blacklists/whitelists for your websites, and you would want to use the "Error Pages" section of the website configuration to set a custom error page for the 403.6 "IP address rejected" error.